# SQL CE Erro Insert na Base de dados

Tags: c#, sql, mobile

Estou criar uma aplicação para um PDA, quanto tento fazer a inserção de dados na base de dados encontro sempre este erro.

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 100,Token in error = ) ]

```
public static bool InsertPedido(int id, int Vim, DateTime date, int quantidade)
{ 
    SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=" + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + @"\\DataPedido.sdf; Password =SUPER2000PED;");

    conn.Open();
    try
    { 
        SqlCeCommand comando = new SqlCeCommand(@"INSERT INTO Pedido([IDLayout], [Vim], [Data], [Quantidade])VALUES(@IDLayout,@Vim,@Data,@Quantidade))", conn); 

        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDLatout", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vim", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Vim;
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = date;
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantidade", SqlDbType.Int).Value = quantidade;

        int row = comando.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Há dois parêntesis sendo fechados no final da String da query.

Comment: Esta pergunta é sobre um pequeno erro de digitação. Ela é específica demais.

Comment: Engraçado! Acabei agora de rever uma questão igual no SO.com: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22096468/2556111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá... o problema está na sua query. ela possui no fim um parenteses a mais

```
SqlCeCommand comando = new SqlCeCommand(@"INSERT INTO Pedido([IDLayout], [Vim], [Data], [Quantidade])VALUES(@IDLayout,@Vim,@Data,@Quantidade))", conn);
```

O correto seria assim

```
SqlCeCommand comando = new SqlCeCommand(@"INSERT INTO Pedido([IDLayout], [Vim], [Data], [Quantidade])VALUES(@IDLayout,@Vim,@Data,@Quantidade)", conn);
```

Veja que no fim do Insert, antes do ",conn);" possuía 2 parenteses )), você precisa remover um deles

Comment: Engraçado! Acabei agora de rever uma questão igual no SO.com: Foi você que deu também a resposta em http://stackoverflow.com/a/22096508/2556111 ?

Comment: Não não, a resposta não fui eu, mas o dono da pergunta é o mesmo

Comment: @ramaral o autor da pergunta seguiu uma sugestão do próprio meta nosso, [veja aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/735/3117), tá certo que foi uma pergunta sem grandes desafios, então parece meio sem graça. Já o tchicotti não fez nada de errado.

Comment: @Math Obrigada pelo esclarecimento. Já agora gostava de saber quem votou na pergunta.

Comment: @ramaral sou homem! rs.. Sim, o voto a favor da pergunta foi algo muito displicente, na minha opinião. Mas isso é algo que tenho visto com frequência por aqui no SO Pt.

Comment: @Math É verdade! Tenho notado que, mal as perguntas aparecem, já têm voto a favor. Alguém que anda desesperado por medalhas!